# Decorator pattern - Restrict the decorators to specific types of components

Tags: design-patterns, decorator

What do you do for the cases when your decorator is applied to an incompatible component?

If you consider the classic example given to illustrate the use of the pattern, the graphical window, what happens if you apply (say) a scrollbar decorator to a dialog ("dialog" being a concrete window component having a fixed size)?  Or rather, what "should" happen?  (I'm thinking that ideally "nothing" should happen, at least in terms of what the user of the scrollbar-decorated-dialog sees on their screen, but I'm more interested in strategies to avoid people doing stupid things.)

Answer (score 4):

> but I'm more interested in strategies to avoid people doing stupid things

You can achieve this by using the [marker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern) interface pattern.

- Define an interface called `Scrollable`.
- All components that support the scrolling functionality will implement this interface. For example, a `Window` is `Scrollable` and should thus implement this interface.
- The concrete `ScrollDecorator` implementation will have `Scrollable` instance variable and a constructor that takes a `Scrollable` argument.
- By making the `ScrollDecorator` constructor take a `Scrollable` arguemnt, you can now restrict the `ScroallDecorator` to be able to decorate only those instances that are `Scrollable`.

Since this is a language agnostic question, the words "interface" and "implement" should not be associated with the Java programming language but the general definition instead. That said, here is a coded version of the points discussed above in Java :

Let's first take a look at final desired state of the solution :

```
 Component window =  new ScrollDecorator(new Window());//should be allowed
 Component dialog = new ScrollDecorator(new Dialog());//should not be allowed.
```

An attempt to decorate a dialog with a scrollbar will result in a compilation error. Let's now look at the classes that make this possible :

**Component**

```
public interface Component {
    public void load();
}
```

**Scrollable (The marker interface)**

```
public interface Scrollable extends Component {

}
```

**Concrete Component (Window)**

```
public class Window implements Scrollable {

    @Override
    public void load() {
        //code for drawing a window.        
    }

}
```

**Concrete Component (Dialog)**

```
class Dialog implements Component {

    @Override
    public void load() {
        //code for drawing a dialog.        
    }

}
```

**ScrollDecorator**

```
public class ScrollDecorator implements Component {

    private Scrollable scrollable;

    public ScrollDecorator(Scrollable scrollable) {
        this.scrollable = scrollable;
    }

    @Override
    public void load() {
        scrollable.load();
        //code for drawing a scrollbar over the scrollable component

    }
}
```

Other language specific options that can be used to achieve this are annotations in Java or custom attributes in .NET.

Comment: This approach works if you own the classes that you wish to decorate, but the Decorator pattern is often used on third-party classes. What if you have no control over `Window` and `Dialog`, and cannot change the fact that `Dialog` extends `Window`?

Comment: @jaco0646 I believe that is a question you should be asking the OP. In my opinion, the statements "What do you do for the cases when **your** decorator is applied to an incompatible component?" and "but **I'm** more interested in strategies to avoid **people** doing stupid things" indicate that the OP is the owner of the API :). That said, it's the client code that will have to implement a way to stop their developers from doing stupid things. I don't think that's what the OP is looking for here though..